# Is Hadoop going to give me more benefits in my case?

Tags: xml, clojure, jvm, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using Clojure to pull ten XML files hourly, each file is about 10 MB.  This script is running on a server machine.
XML files are parsed and stored into RDBMS right now  (all is done using native Clojure code).

Considering my case, Am I going to gain more benefits if I used Hadoop Map/Reduce to parse the XML files? or it will be overkill?

Comment: What benefits are you after? I'd be surprised if each file took more than a few seconds to process anyway...?

Comment: @Greg Yes indeed. I'm just wondering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Hadoop would definitely be an overkill in this case. If you were to use Hadoop to parse 10 files, parallely,

- It would spawn 10 JVMs from each Map task
- It could spawn 1 more JVM for the reduce task (ofcourse you could have a map only hadoop job where u wont need a reduce phase)
- There would be a shuffle stage between the Map and Reduce phase where all Map output is sent across the network to the reduce node

If your files are each a max of 10 Mb, then I dont see much advantage and you will infact incur significant overhead from the JVM starts and excessive IO.

Id say you should consider Hadoop once you cross 100 - 150 Mb per file

Answer (score 3):

I have two clojure examples that you could use for comparison:

- 1 application parsing thousands of xml files each around 1Mb or less, and processing is around 50ms each under normal load.
- 1 other application doing processing on relatively big log files, each of 50mb-100mb, and processing is around 1-2seconds each.

Of course, this depends on the server processing power, but everything is done in clojure, without any hint of a bottleneck.

Comment: +1 for some interesting real life numbers! Quite impressive what speed you are getting out of Clojure. Out of interest what XML processing libraries are you using?

Comment: A slightly changed copy of [Clojure wrapper for saxon](https://github.com/pjt/saxon). Using a lot of parallel code executing precompiled xquery queries.